# Colorbar changes on export in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, export, colorbar

I'm trying to do a 3d cone plot in plotly with a custom colorscale that only changes in the opacity of the color I'm using. In the preview window everything seems fine:

[image: Visualization of a magnetic globule, the colorbar on the right is totally fine]

But when I'm exporting the image using the snapshot icon, the colorbar becomes monochrome:

[image: Visualization of a magnetic globule, the colorbar is rigged]

Here's my code:

```py
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from emknot import *

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)
z = np.linspace(-3, 3, 7)


cones = []

for i in x:
    for j in y:
        for k in z: 
            print(i)
            u = [globule([i, j, k],k=1)[0]]
            v = [globule([i, j, k],k=1)[1]]
            w = [globule([i, j, k],k=1)[2]]

            cones.append(go.Cone(
            x=[i],
            y=[j],
            z=[k],
            u=u,
            v=v,
            w=w,
            cmin=0,
            cmax=1.5,
            colorscale=[[0,'rgba(255,255,255, 0)'],[1,'rgba(0,0,255,1)']],
            sizemode="absolute",
            sizeref=0.6,
            anchor="center")) 


layout = go.Layout(title='EM-globule')
fig = go.Figure(data=cones, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

## Solution #1 (kind of)

When manually exporting using `fig.write_image("fig1.svg")`, the problem doesn't occur. But now I have to deal with the camera controls to get a better picture of my globule ;)